# IMAP Client processing emails using perl

Tags: perl, imap

I am using the following to connect to a mail server and get the subject and body of the emails using the code below.

```
my $subject = $imap->subject($msg) or do { print "Error obtaining Subject of $msg : $@";  next; };
```

I get output like below. Do we know how to convert the output into human readable format.  I tried using the decode to base64 with out any luck.  Please help.

=?utf-8?B?UkU6IFJlYXNzaWduZWTCoHzCoFByaW9yaXR5OsKgTG93wqB8IEluY2lkZW50?= =?utf-8?B?OsKgSU5DMDAwMDAwODQxMjc4wqA=?=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-ASCII header fields in mails are encoded with [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). It can be decoded with [Encode::MIME::Header](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/MIME/Header.html):

```
use Encode 'decode';
print decode('MIME-Header',
    '=?utf-8?B?UkU6IFJlYXNzaWduZWTCoHzCoFByaW9yaXR5OsKgTG93wqB8IEluY2lkZW50?=
     =?utf-8?B?OsKgSU5DMDAwMDAwODQxMjc4wqA=?=');
```

Comment: Thank you very much .

Comment: Hi Steffen Ullrich - How to decode the body contents using the above?

Comment: @user3232560: This is a completely different question and can not be done with the same method. Have a look for example at MIME::Tools.